# Interpretation of typeperf counters for loopback interface

Tags: windows, performance, performance-monitoring, perfmon

I have collected performance statistics using typeperf for the following counters:

1. Network Interface(MS TCP Loopback interface)\Bytes Total/sec   10 203 372
2. Network Interface(MS TCP Loopback interface)\Current Bandwidth 10 000 000

How to explain that the actual throughput is higher then the bandwidth? Bandwidth normalized to bytes it is 1 250 000 bytes/sec. Even if the bandwidth is per one core and the machine has 8 cores, the bandwidth becomes 10 000 000 and it is still lower then 10 203 372.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the bandwidth of a network interface is a constant value which determines for which *type* of network this interface was designed (in this case 10MB network?).

But (and now I'm guessing) I think that there is not built-in limit in the interface card which would artificially decrease the throughput if it is going over the designed value. If the manufacturer did a good job and created a quality card, which is capable of handling the transfer speeds little bit higher than designed, then good for you.

Also - you are observing only 2% increase - that is, I believe, statistically not important ;).